# How to overlay raster files and vector files and save as tiff?

Tags: python, vector, gis, raster, arcgis

I have a remote sensing image (TIF) and a corresponding vector file (SHP). I want to overlay the vectors (points, lines, and surfaces) onto the TIF image according to the corresponding projection and save them as a TIF image. According to the experience of others on the forum, adding a band to the TIF has caused some problems, and the TIF I need is still three bands. I just replace the positions with other pixel values where the vectors overlap, And other locations are still the original remote sensing images.

According to the experience of others on the forum, I added a band to the TIF. At this point, I encountered some problems. The processed image was opened using ArcGIS and no trace of the vector was found, and the TIF I needed was still three bands.